# Javascript - if statements regarding returns and views

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want to consolidate these if statements to make this efficient as possible while still having it be able to perform case 1 alone, case 2 alone, case 1 and 2 together, and neither case 1 nor case 2. Is there a way to do this?

```
if(x >= 100 && y < 100){
return(
    <View>
        <Text>
            this is case 1
        </Text>
    </View>          
)}            
if(x < 100 && y >= 100){
return(
    <View>
        <Text>
            this is case 2
        </Text>
    </View>          
)}
if(x < 100 && y < 100){
return(
    <View>
        <Text>
            this is case 1
        </Text>
    </View>
    <View>
        <Text>
            this is case 2
        </Text>
    </View>                    
)}
if(x >= && y >= 100){
return(
    <View>
        <Text>
            this is case 4
        </Text>
    </View>          
)}
```

Comment: The last case doesn't need `if`, since it runs if none of the previous cases were true.

Comment: You only test `x > 100` and `x < 100`. What about `x == 100`?

Comment: Is the last case supposed to be `if(x > 100 && y > 100)`? Comparisons don't automatically distribute over `&&`.

Comment: Fixed those thanks! Any ideas on how to make this less lines of code by consolidating some if statements?

Answer (score 1):

Put your return value in a variable that you can concatenate for each case.

```
retval = '';
if (y < 100) {
    retval += 
        <View>
            <Text>
                this is case 1
            </Text>
        </View>          
    ;
}
if (x < 100) {
    retval += 
        <View>
            <Text>
                this is case 2
            </Text>
        </View>
    ;
}
if (retval == '') {
    // neither case
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>
                this is case 4
            </Text>
        </View>          
    );
} else {
    return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could collect the wanted strings and return either the formatted collection or case four.

```
const take = [];

if (x < 100) take.push('this is case 2');
if (y < 100) take.push('this is case 1');

return take.length
    ? take.map(/* your formatting */)
    : 'this is case 4';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const el1 = (
    <View>
        <Text>
            this is case 1
        </Text>
    </View>          
)
const el2 = (
    <View>
        <Text>
            this is case 2
        </Text>
    </View>    
)
...

const conditions = {
    el1,
    el2,
    ...
}

if (x >= 100 && y < 100)
    return conditions.el1
else if (x < 100 && y >= 100)
    return conditions.el2
else if (x < 100 && y < 100)
    return conditions.el1 + conditions.el2
else
    return conditions.default || ''
```